# Diferencias entre la parte pública y la parte privada de una clase

Tags: c++, clase

La duda principal que tengo a parte de estas diferencias es:

¿Con qué criterio decido qué poner en la parte pública y qué poner en la parte privada de la `class`?

Gracias de antemano.

PD: el tema por el que viene la duda no toca `POO`.

Comment: Pues básicamente digamos que deberían de ser privados aquellos métodos que son usados dentro de la misma clase y que no queremos que puedan a llegar a ser usados fuera de la clase, y publicos aquellos que son necesarios compartir con otras clases o que son necesarios al momento de crear una instancia de esa clase.

Comment: Voto por dejarla abierta. Si bien en principio cada cual puede usar `public`, `protected` y `private` como le plazca, hay *casos de uso* poco menos que *universales* para cada una.

Comment: Yo he votado por dejarla abierta, pero creo que quizás sería bueno no centrarse en C++ y hacerla una pregunta de [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico]

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro la sintaxis es más o menos la misma en otros lenguajes?(porque solo me he metido con C, C++) la edito sin ningún problema para lenguaje-agnostico

Comment: No parece que la pregunta sea sobre sintaxis. "¿Qué debería poner como `public`, `protected` y `private` en una clase?" es algo independiente del lenguaje, y valdría igual para C++, Java, PHP, Ruby, Delphi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fácil:

- `public`: aquello que se quiera dejar disponible *desde fuera* de la clase. Es tu *interfaz* de uso.
- `protected`: funciones internas, *detalles de implementación*, que **no han de ser usadas** por código *usuario* de tu clase, **PERO** que si son útiles tenerlas disponibles en **clases herederas** de la misma.

Consejo: coloca `protected` **todo lo que puedas** y lo vas cambiando a `public` **cuando no te quede mas remedio**. Es decir, si *una determinada funcionalidad es el motivo de existir de tu clase* y es imprescindible para su correcto uso, **entonces** `public`. En cualquier otro caso, `protected`.

#### Edito

#### Modos de acceso a los métodos y *atributos* de una clase:

- `public`:

Accesibles **para todo el mundo**.

- `protected`:

Accesible para las funciones miembro y funciones *amigas* (`friend`), **tanto de nuestra propia clase como de clases *hijas***.

- `private`:

Accesible **solo** para las funciones miembro y *amigas* de la propia clase.

A lo anterior, hay que añadir el tipo de herencia:

```
class A: public B { ... };
```

- Miembros públicos en A resultan públicos en B.
- Miembros protegidos en A resultan protegidos en B.
- Miembros privados en A resultan privados en B.

`class A: protected B { ... };`

- Miembros públicos en A resultan protegidos en B.
- Miembros protegidos en A resultan protegidos en B.
- Miembros privados en A resultan privados en B.

`class A: private B { ... };`

- Miembros públicos en A resultan privados en B.
- Miembros protegidos en A resultan privados en B.
- Miembros privados en A resultan privados en B.

Comment: `protected` es lo mismo que `private`?

Comment: No. `private` es, por así decirlo, *mas restrictivo*; pero solo aplica a las clases derivadas. *Desde fuera* de la clase, es lo mismo.

Comment: es que no hay ni un solo apunte en todo el temario que mencione `protected`, nos movemos con `private`. Entiendo que si desde fuera de la clase es lo mismo se le da un uso muy parecido.

Comment: En realidad, no se usa mucho. Vamos, yo no lo uso nunca xD

Comment: Pues valla *mie..a* de temario. Cuando empieces a trabajar la herencia, verás que es al revés. Mucho `protected`, y ningún `private`.

Comment: Herencia no entra en la asignatura, solo vemos estructuras de datos, vamos TADs. Osea que `private` conforme avance ¿casi ni lo utilizaré?

Comment: No te puedo responder **seguro** a eso. Yo soy *aficionado autodidacta*. Pero en mi código, y en los que he visto, el `private` **apenas** se usa. Su uso principal es para *ocultar* funcionalidad a clases hijas. No tiene mucho sentido, salvo en casos concretos y excepcionales.

Comment: Me has aclarado bastante, gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 2):

Los compañeros ya te han explicado las diferencias entre los ámbitos publico y privado, por tanto me limitaré a proponerte un criterio de selección de ámbitos para tus atributos y métodos.

Primordialmente nos enseñan que el ámbito de los atributos esta orientado al encapsulamiento, algo así:

```
private: 
    short edad;
public: 
    void setEdad(short edad) {
        this->edad = edad;
    }
    short getEdad() {
        return this->edad;
    }
```

Como opinión personal lo anterior para mi no tendría ningún sentido a menos que realizases una validación u algo que justifique encapsular, como esto:

```
private: 
    short edad;
public: 
    void setEdad(short edad) {
        if (edad >= 0 && edad <= 969) { //La edad de Matusalén
            this->edad = edad;
        }
    }
    short getEdad() {
        return this->edad;
    }
```

En el caso que uno de tus atributos posean un método modificador `set` y un método selector `get` del tipo:

```
void setAtributo(tipo dato) {
    Atributo = dato;
}
short getAtributo() {
    return Atributo;
}
```

Esto podría ser un indicador para solo declararlo como publico y así ahorrarte dos funciones de juguete, aclaro que solo optaría por declararlo publico si se que en un futuro jamas haré nada para controlar la modificación o selección de este atributo.

Ahora hablemos de los métodos, sucede que algunas veces tienes una función publica que a ciencia cierta realiza un montón de acciones, algo así:

```
public: 
    void TrabajarCosas() {
        //Un montón de lineas que sirven para validar esas cosas
        //Un montón de lineas que sirven para preparar esas cosas
        //Un montón de lineas que sirven para  hacer algo con esas cosas
    }
```

Imagina que quieres aferrarte a que si divides vencerás, entonces terminaras por manejar el criterio de que una función debería hacer una única cosa y hacerla bien «Recomendado leer **Code Clean**» entonces terminarías con algo como esto:

```
private:    
    void validarCosas() {}
    void prepararCosas() {}
    void hacerAlgoConCosas() {}
public:
    void TrabajarCosas() {
        validarCosas();
        prepararCosas();
        hacerAlgoConCosas();
    }
```

Ten en cuenta que el método que interesa exponer públicamente es aquel que trabaja con las cosas pues en realidad esta acción agrupa una cantidad de procedimientos que deban ejecutarse en un orden especifico y ademas que por si solos no cumplan un propósito, y que es posible que por legibilidad o mantenimiento prefieras disponerlos de forma separada, pero debido a que de forma independiente no son útiles quizás no quieras que sean invocados, por ello decides que son privados.

*Espero que les sea de utilidad y que tanta verborrea no termine por confundirlos*.

Comment: Gracias por explicarme un criterio para elegir, era lo único que se me resistía un poco, aunque tenía una idea muy vaga.